# What is the right technique to use Mocks for Unit test

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito

I'm a complete newbie to testing.

 Suppose there is a simple method that sends a request to some third-party API and returns an object constructed from the received json:

```
public Object getAirQualityIndex(int id) {
    try {
        String stationInfoUrl = aqIndexUrlPattern.replace("{id}", String.valueOf(id));
        HttpRequest stationRequest = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
                .uri(URI.create(stationInfoUrl))
                .GET()
                .build();
        HttpResponse<String> stationResponse = HttpClient.newBuilder()
                .build()
                .send(stationRequest, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
        if (stationResponse.statusCode() != 200) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Air Quality Index is currently unavailable, " +
                    "status code " + stationResponse.statusCode());
        }
        return new ObjectMapper().readValue(stationResponse.body(), new TypeReference<>() {});
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("failed to get station measures information", e);
    }
}
```

It can be divided into several private methods, but in this case, I think it will not change the essence of the issue.

Now I want to write a unit test for this method, do I understand correctly that for this I need to create a Mock for the dependencies such as: `HttpResponse.statusCode()`, `HttpResponse.body()`, `ObjectMapper().readValue(...)`?  But it seems to me that then the whole test will just check if `if (statusCode != 200)` works, because I will replace everything else with Mocks so that nothing could fail, is there any practical sense in such a test?

Next, there is a method that allows you to save the resulting object to a file, in which form it saves it is not so important, but suppose it is **pdf** using `itext7`:

```
public void writeAirQualityIndexAsPdf(Object aqIndex, Path destPath) throws IOException {
    PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(destPath.toFile()));
    Document document = new Document(pdf);

    String aqIndexYaml = new YAMLMapper()
            .writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter()
            .withRootName("AirQualityIndex")
            .writeValueAsString(aqIndex);
    //replaced spaces with \u00A0 to prevent itext7 to trim whitespaces
    document.add(new Paragraph(aqIndexYaml.replaceAll(" ", "\u00A0")));
    document.close();
}
```

There’s not even much of my code here, which can be tested if everything is replaced with Mocks, it can even be rewrited as a one-liner... So how should I test this method?

Maybe I just misunderstand something in the ideas of unit tests and it’s not worth creating a Mock for every third-party calls?

Comment: Unit tests (see also integration tests) should have no external dependencies since they should run fast/often, and as part of a build.  If it fails, then did it fail because the external dependency was not available or because a bug was introduced?  The example is *hard to test* because of what looks like use of static methods.  The typical approach is to wrap static classes in a class that can be instantiated, and inject them through the constructor.  For testing, the wrappers can be mocked and set up to return the appropriate objects to trigger the various paths through the code.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can use for unit test some libs like [WireMock](https://wiremock.org/). This will helps you to reproduce behaviour with different response codes and bodies. Also with WireMock you could assert requests headers and url.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).